# Frequency that a discrete brownian motion with drift process exceeds its previous maximum

Tags: brownian-motion, gaussian

This question relates to the frequency with which a discretely observed brownian motion exceeds its all time high.

Assume my retirement portfolio's value can be modelled as a process with normally distributed returns, upwards drift of μ per year and standard deviation of δ per year.

Today my portfolio hits an all time high, and I take my family for dinner. I promise to take them out for dinner at every subsequent all time high.

How many days per year do I expect to take them out?

Is the single parameter needed σ/μ?

Is the probability biased upwards because I'm starting at an all time high? What is the steady state probability?

A crude monte carlo simulation shows that I take them out for roughly 11% of days if σ=μ. Clearly if σ=0 I take them every day.

Is there a closed form solution?

I also read that since 1950, the US stockmarket has reached all time highs on about 7% of days.  Empirical returns are fat-tailed not normally distributed, does this make much difference?

This is not an interview question or class homework, I just make it up, because I was actually thinking of doing the restaurant thing!

Comment: This set of points isn't discrete (you can see that because the running maximum process has continuous paths). However, you can fix a series of sampling times $t_i$ and then define $t_j$ to be a record time if $X_{t_j}>X_{t_i}$ for all $i<j$. Then the problem is well-posed. I think the problem of whether a single time in a sequence is a record in this sense is a fairly straightforward problem with integrating a multivariate normal distribution, but the question of how many $t_i$ among $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are records seems like it involves some nastier combinatorics.

Comment: I assumed daily observations at the market close each day.  The usual rule of thumb in finance is something around 250 trading days per year.  Yes, I want the steady state probability that t_i is a record.